# Group array of objects based on the object's key/value-pair which is in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been really going at this problem, where I have to group an array of object based on the object's subproperty key/value-pairs. If managed to get it working if it's on the first level with distinct key/values (in this case "name"), but not when it's based on array values in the containing object. Appreciate any help!

I want to go from:

```
let array = [
    {name: 'Name1', classes: [
        {className: 'class1'}, {className: 'class2'}
    ]}, 
    {name: 'Name2', classes: [
        {className: 'class1'}
    ]}, 
    {name: 'Name3', classes: [
        {className: 'class2'}
    ]}
];
```

into something like:

```
let resultArray = [
    {
      class1: [
        { name: 'Name1', classes: [{ className: 'class1' }, { className: 'class2' }] },
        { name: 'Name2', classes: [{ className: 'class1' }] }
      ]
    },
    {
      class2: [
        { name: 'Name1', classes: [{ className: 'class1' }, { className: 'class2' }] },
        { name: 'Name3', classes: [{ className: 'class2' }] }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Edit: sorry, didn't add the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. What I had before was:

```
const groupByKey = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce((r, v, i, a, k = v.name) => {
    const rTemp = r;
    rTemp[k] = rTemp[k] ? rTemp[k] : [];
    rTemp[k].push(v);
    return rTemp;
  }, {});
```

which presented it grouped on name (which is not what I wanted obviously, but works on "first level")

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: Show your [mcve] and the results you get.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't quite understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce`

```
array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.classes.forEach(cls => {
    if(acc[cls.className]) {
      acc[cls.className].push(curr);
    } else {
      acc[cls.className] = [curr];
    }
  })
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier Implementation

```js
let array = [
    {
        name: 'Name1', classes: [
            { className: 'class1' }, { className: 'class2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Name2', classes: [
            { className: 'class1' }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Name3', classes: [
            { className: 'class2' }
        ]
    }
];

let resultArray = []

array.forEach(function (element) {
    element.classes.forEach(function (innerelement) {
        if (!resultArray[innerelement.className])
            resultArray[innerelement.className] = []
        resultArray[innerelement.className].push(element);
    })
})
console.log(resultArray)
```

Comment: If you're gong to do that, you probably want to get rid of your output and instead utilize the "code snippet" feature.

Comment: Thanks for that, Next time i will try code snippet.

Comment: Or just try it this time... note you're treating `resultArray` like a dictionary instead of an array.